# Remove duplicates for consecutive values using pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How to handle below scenario using pig script. 
If we have consecutive rows with first two columns having same data, only first row needs to be selected and rest of the rows need to be discarded. Also this needs to be done after time is sorted.

Example:
Input records:

```
**Account**   **id**        **time**
account 1                20150214180057
account 1     21869      20150214180059
account 1     41866      20150214175753
account 1     41866      20150214176103
account 1     21869      20150214190059
account 1     41866      20150214185753
account 1     78343      20150214185900
account 1     78343      20150214189753
account 1     78343      20150214190003
account 1     21869      20150214190003
account 1     98766      20150214190003
account 1     98766      20150214190003
```

Output Record

```
**Account**   **id**       **time**
account 1      41866    20150214175753
account 1      21869    20150214180059
account 1      41866    20150214185753
account 1      78343    20150214185900
account 1      21869    20150214190003
account 1      98766    20150214190003
account 1      21869    20150214190059
```

I tried using Rank, but problem is all the records with similar account & id are coming under one rank and when I select first record, remaining records are discarded. So this logic doesn't work.

Please give me an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try FILTER function and DISTINCT function on **id**

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to group by account and then have a UDF that iterates over the resulting bag and eliminate not wanted entries. Outside of a bag you have no chance of taking consecutive records into account as this is against map reduce paradigm. MR assumes you can process every record independently.

Comment: Thanks LiMuBei.. I grouped by account and wrote UDF to read bag of tuples, compare consecutive records and returning wanted records.